# how to integrate spring batch admin into exisiting maven project

Tags: spring-batch-admin

I want to integrate spring batch admin into my existing maven project. Also i want that only one war file should generate that of my existing maven project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rajeev Ranjan

The Spring batch admin web UI is a reference implementation. Most of it is customizable and is externalized from code into XML files and UI templates.

See https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/tree/master/batch-core/src/main/resources/WEB-INF for  an example of how I have embedded it into my own application. Screen shots from this are available here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/wiki/Trooper-Batch-Web-Console

Answer (score 1):

one way is to achieve this is to create your maven project a web app project and copy the spring batch admin sample web resource (web.xml, index.jsp as minimum) to it. add spring-batch-admin-manager and spring-batch-admin-resource dependency in your pom. build your application war and you are done.